# How to get the scanner working on printer HP M2727MFP and Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: system-installation, software-recommendation, software-installation

How to install the scanner working on printer HP M2727MFP and Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

Install scanner drivers :

```
sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev
```

Then use the scanner with the package `simple-scan`